# Why does my android app only work in flight mode?

Tags: android

I created an app in Android studio using maps and geo location with great success.  I've recently updated my phone handset (Samsung J6 Plus) to Pie 9.0 but now the app will not load on my phone or on the virtual device within Android studio.  It will load however, when my phone and the virtual device is set to flight mode.

I've updated Android studio to 3.4.1 and updated the support repository SDK Tools, SDK Platform-Tools, Emulator and SDK build-tools 29-rc3.

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;


//Changed from Stackflow - public class AR_MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback
public class AR_MapsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);


            return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    LocationListener locationListener;
    LocationManager locationManager;

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) ;
            {
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                    ;
                {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(locationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 30, 5, locationListener);
                }
            }
        }
    }



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ar_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }


    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        //RM Adding the code from the location activity Lecture 97 LocationManager and listener
        locationManager = (LocationManager)this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationListener = new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

                //Added a Toast - for demo and then added the code for the location
                mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
                // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
                LatLng userLocation = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
                mMap.clear();
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(userLocation).title("AR Projects HQ"));
                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(userLocation, 16));

                //Added 06-03-2019 to add another pointer on map
                LatLng randy = new LatLng(50.877644, -2.108941);
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(randy).title("Randy HQ"));

                LatLng roddy = new LatLng(50.876722, -2.101839);
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(roddy).title("Roddy HQ"));
                //Hardcoded another pointer on the map


            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

            }
        };

        //RM - Adding code from location activity
        //RM - WAS - if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 28)

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 28)
        {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 30, 5, locationListener);
        } else {

            //RM - Checks for permission from phone
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) !=PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);
                 else    {

                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 30, 5, locationListener);

                    Location lastKnownLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

                mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);

                LatLng userLocation = new LatLng(lastKnownLocation.getLatitude(), lastKnownLocation.getLongitude());
                mMap.clear();

                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(userLocation).title("AR Projects HQ"));
                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(userLocation, 16));
                }
            }
    }
}
```

The app will prompt to request location but then crash out, the message will then say that the App keeps stopping.  This is the same on my phone and virtual emulator, which is set on Pie 9.0 API 28.  However the app will load when airline mode is selected but as this is a map based app it will not display the map.

Comment: You should add the error message from logcat that you're getting. It'll help a lot in knowing what the problem is.

Comment: Ok thanks, will do ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a blind answer because you didn't provide your Log, but you may facing a common problem, 
if your app is targeting API level 28 (Android 9.0) or above and your are using play-services-maps dependency version 16.0.0 or lower versions you have to implement this in your AndroidManifest file :

```
<uses-library
  android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
  android:required="false" />
```

This is handled for you if you are using

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0
```

here is the full documentation :

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/config#specify_requirement_for_apache_http_legacy_library

Comment: Thanks, that's great.  it did the job! :)

Comment: @RoddyMorrison if the answer helped you, i would appreciate accepting answer and upvote, happy coding :)

Comment: Yes, sorry for taking so long to get back to you, it worked a treat :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, I added the code after

```
</activity>

<uses-library
  android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
  android:required="false" />

</application>
```